# How can I make my onboard HDMI to work with my GPU?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, tv

I want to use my TV as a second monitor through HDMI in the motherboard, while use my main monitor through my graphics card since my motherboard is the only one who allows it.

Ubuntu won't detect my TV unless I make iGPU (integrated in the motherboard) my primary display, if I do that, my GPU is disabled, and I will have to connect the VGA to my motherboard. It works but I run into issues with compiz, but still I don't use my real GPU, only everything on the motherboard and the integrated graphics card.

How do I make ubuntu detect my iGPU and with my GPU as well and not only choose my primary one? (that way HDMI on the TV is rendered by the CPU graphics, while my main monitor is my real GPU.)

Thanks :)

These are my specs:

CPU: i7 2600k
GPU: HD 4870
MOTHERBOARD: Asus P8Z68-V Pro (z68)